# How to embed live streaming video content into unity player (android)

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, live-streaming, unity-game-engine, m3u8

I am trying to make an application which can livestream a football or a cricket match directly from [hotstar](http://www.hotstar.com/) or [starsports](http://www.starsports.com/cricket/index.html) or for that matter any website which shows live sports content. On a bit of research I have come to know these video players use m3u8 encryption and when we try to access this streaming content, we are getting access denied inside the unity player. We can embed any html5 web page. Also can run youtube live streaming content however are not able to decrypt these videos.

Is there any particular strategy/method that can be followed to livestream sports content into unity player?

Any inputs on direction to go forward would be appreaciated.

**EDIT**

On further research I got to know that if any particular link with m3u8 encryption runs well in [akamai](http://players.akamai.com/ios) then it would also run inside unity webplayer. However hotstar link does not work here. It throws an "access denied" message.

[image: link to be used for fetching m3u8 link]

It seems we must use this particular link change a few characters in order to fetch the m3u8 link. However I am not able to figure out exactly what needs to be done.